# Atmel Studio 7 doesn't show any debugging tools

Tags: c, debugging, atmel, atmelstudio

I just installed Atmel Studio 7 on my Windows 10 HP laptop. This is my first time working w/ a C compiler since high school, and my first time working with a microcontroller.

I loaded one of their example projects and built it without any errors. However, I am not able to debug since there is no option for a debugging tool (see screenshot). The only option is for  'Custom programming tool', while their tutorial videos all show an option for a SAM-ICE debugger or Simulator (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QlDSNeuAdY)

I have spent hours trying to find an issue online w/ no luck. Please help!

[image]

Comment: I think you need to connect a debugger to PC. May be a USB debugger!

Comment: @GauravPathak but shouldn't I be able to debug via the simulator?

Comment: @DankMasterDan Did you select a device first?

Comment: Not all devices are supported by the simulator. In general, the ARM based devices (SAM) are not.

Comment: make sure that u choose atmega8 or atmega16
if it doesn't work .. try another solution

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem. I solved this by [unchecking the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJwob.png) Tools->Options->Debugger->Backend Agent-> Start Local Backend Agent and then [checking that box again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klSPY.png)

Comment: This just worked perfectly for me on the latest build at the end of 2022 after debugging for some time, and EDBG seemingly randomly disappearing!

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this information as I also just spent a fair amount of time trying to determine why no debugging tool was available as an option:

**Make sure you have the right device connected.**

I know this sounds terribly basic, but in my case I have both SAML21 and SAML22 Xplained Pro boards, and I'd forgotten which one I had targeted for a particular project. If you have a project open that targets one, but the attached device is different, you may have this problem. The only available option becomes "Custom Programming Tool" which isn't helpful.

After connecting the correct board, I had to revisit the `Tool` menu and change the selected debugger/programmer to the appropriate (only) `EDBG • ATML######` option.

*If you're not using an Atmel Xplained board, this may not be applicable.*

Answer (score 0):

I spend some time about this problem as well and found out that all I had to do was go to **Device and Debugging** options then go to **Build** and select **All Configurations** in the configuration box then the simulator should appear under tools.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was atbackend.exe which crashed after hibernating my laptop. I had to stop Atmel studio, ensure that no AtmelStudio or atbackend processes exist in system and then start ATmel STudio again. After that Simulator appeared in Tool-Selected debugger/programmer.